# what is the difference between " get in the bus" and " get on the bus"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origin/reason for the expression “on the bus” instead of “in the bus”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251/origin-reason-for-the-expression-on-the-bus-instead-of-in-the-bus)

I want to know when to use " get in the bus." and " get on the bus."
I will thank you If you give me the right answer.

Comment: Wow. I wish I had thought of this example when I was leaving [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83088/feel-free-to-hit-me-up-at-on-via/83097#comment164954_83097) a few days ago. _On the bus_ – what a great example to illustrate how _on_ doesn't always mean _atop_ or _attached to_. Truth is, prepositions are very versatile words with several usages, nuances, and idiomatic meanings. I suppose we get "on" a bus for the same reason we get "on" a train – because it's short for getting "on board" the bus – but, until now, I hadn't thought much about _in_ being a better word.

Answer (score 2):

You never *get in the bus* unless it's a small bus the size of a car; you always *get on the bus*. But you *get in a car* not the other way around. I guess, it has to do with the size of these machines.

Comment: Generally speaking, Noah, I'm in agreement with you, although, in some locales, there's a big difference between being _on_ the bus, and _in_ the bus, as is depicted [here](http://blogosapiens.typepad.com/photos/colombie/bus.jpg).

Comment: @J.R. In that case I would never get *in* there. *On* seems to be more comfortable. Thank you for the picture.

Comment: I don't know if you can get *on the bus* if it's not taking you from one point to another. If you're looking for a place to hide from criminals and see an out-of-service bus, I think you'd say *get in the bus.*