# Can we really "get in" or "get on" a thing?

Tags: prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Origin/reason for the expression “on the bus” instead of “in the bus”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251/origin-reason-for-the-expression-on-the-bus-instead-of-in-the-bus)

Can we really "get in a bus" or "get on a bus" in Standard English usage?

Comment: Also related: [What is the difference between “get in the bus” and “get on the bus”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/what-is-the-difference-between-get-in-the-bus-and-get-on-the-bus)

Comment: I recommend looking up "on" and "in" a dictionary. In [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/in), for example, each word has more than 30 meanings listed. That gives these words a lot of flexibility in usage. If you hear a preposition being used a certain way on a regular basis, chances are, that's an acceptable use in that context.  Or maybe you only asked to post an answer?  In that case, I'll just leave this comment for anyone else who lands on this page.

Comment: This is a duplicate only becase it was never answered in the original question, having repeadedly been cited as a duplicate therein as well.  It is impossible to comment, ask, answer there as it is CLOSED.

Answer (score 0):

The many postulations and subtexts were surprising within a previous such question, as was the fact that no one addressed the flaw within the question.

Instead, would we not "get INTO a bus" or "get ONTO a bus," given that we are referring not to the act of BEING on the bus ALREADY but to the act of actively boarding the bus, hence, the simple difference between the use of the prepositions IN and INTO (on/onto) within Standard English.

Comment: Instead of duplicating the essence of  [question #251](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251/origin-reason-for-the-expression-on-the-bus-instead-of-in-the-bus) so that you can add your comment as an answer, please answer or comment at the original question, and just delete this new answer and question.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why a *bus* should be any different to a *cab*, and here are plenty of written instances of ["hop **into** a cab"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hop+into+a+cab%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @jwpat7 I tried, the original question is CLOSED and will not allow a response.  (I even wrote to moderators, attempting to reply there.  This is what we came up with.)

Comment: @jwpat7 There is NOTHING duplicative about this, as INTO and ONTO are never mentioned within the original... originals, which were repeatedly CLOSED as being duplicates. But, of course, you must know that, no?

Comment: @user26555, the original, [question #251](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251/origin-reason-for-the-expression-on-the-bus-instead-of-in-the-bus), has never been closed.  Both your [question #83905](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83905/can-we-really-get-in-or-get-on-a-thing) and related  [question #83383](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83383/what-is-the-difference-between-get-in-the-bus-and-get-on-the-bus) were closed as duplicates of #251, the question I suggested you reply to.  Feel free to say whatever you like about in, on, onto, into there.